# how can I get the result of a field after it was submitted?

Tags: 8, webforms

I would like to extract the value entered by the user in a form to use it in a custom module.
I use Drupal 8.5.1 and Webform 8.x-5.0-rc10. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a form alter hook you can user `$form_state->getValue('element_name')`.  If you are want to get the final submission's data you could do...

```
$form_object = $form_state->getFormObject();
$webform_submission = ($form_object instanceof WebformSubmissionForm) ? $form_object->getEntity() : NULL;
$value = $webform_submission->getElementData('element_name');
```